# Binomial Distribution Probability - Dice Rolled Once

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I am reading "Schaum's Outline of Statistics". I understand the examples in the book, and as a result, I have produced my own probability question, but I am having difficulty in attempting to solve it.

Using Binomial Distribution:

A fair six-sided die is rolled once.

Calculate the probability of getting either a $1$ or a $4$.

This is what I have attempted:

$Success(P) = 2/6 = 0.\dot3$

$Failure(Q) = 4/6 = 0.\dot6$

$= (^1C_3) (0.\dot3)^1 (0.\dot6)^1-1$

$= 0.3\dot2$

This obviously is not correct. I am attempting to solve this question using Binomial Distribution. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2487672/binomial-distribution-probability-die-rolled-once).

Comment: In truth, I have no guess what your question is.  The answer appears to obviously be $\frac 26$.  What on earth is the confusion?

Comment: I have voted to close this.  If there is an underlying question here please try to ask it coherently.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Whilst the answer is 2/6, is it possible to solve this question using Binomial Distribution?

Comment: If you know the answer is $\frac 26$ why do you say it is $.322$?  Please delete this question and ask another, more carefully considered, one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the binomial formula you still get the same answer:

You need $1$ success out of $1$ try, so:

$$P = {1 \choose 1} \cdot P(Success)^1 \cdot P(Failure)^0 = 1 \cdot \big(\frac{2}{6}\big)^1 \cdot \big(\frac{4}{6}\big)^0 = 1 \cdot \frac{2}{6} \cdot 1 = \frac{2}{6}$$